# How does Ansible decide which group_vars files to apply?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to debug how ansible is populating some of my templates at run time.

I have two files within `group_vars`:

```
foo/etl.yml
prod/etl.yml
```

There are values in `prod/etl.yml` that should override the values in `foo/etl.yml` when the playbook is executed against the `prod` inventory. My command line looks similar to this:

```
ansible-playbook foo.yml -i prod --tag foo-config
```

This produces an output file containing only values from foo/etl.yml, nothing from prod/etl.yml. I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental and I'm trying to learn -- so my question is, is there a way to trace the origin of a value populated into a template?

**Update:** As requested, a simplified version of the `prod` inventory file:

```
[region1-gateways]
gw1.region1.foo.com
gw2.region1.foo.com

[region1-masters]
admin1.region1.foo.com
admin2.region1.foo.com

[region1-nodes]
node1.region1.foo.com
node2.region1.foo.com
node3.region1.foo.com

[gateways:children]
region1-gateways

[masters:children]
region1-masters

[nodes:children]
region1-nodes

[prod:children]
gateways
masters
nodes
```

Comment: Can you show the prod inventory file?

Answer (score 0):

You could place your `etl.yml` file within `group_vars/` directory under the `prod` inventory directory.

- `prod/group_vars/etl.yml`

Depending on how you include the `foo/etc.yml` this should override the settings with the content of `prod/group_vars/etl.yml`.

Comment: This might solve the problem in the example but what I'm really asking is how, in general, to get ansible to show what values were used/overridden, etc. Something like a DEBUG-level of verbosity.

Comment: To show what variables for a certain host are set you can use `ansible -m debug -a "var=hostvars['<hostname>']" localhost` ... but as far as I know there is no way to see what file/location were the source for that variable value.